# PHP arrays building tree

Tags: php, arrays, tree

Here is the array indexes are parent's id.
0 is the top parent inside of index of 0 contains sub categories and subs have sub in index keys in the whole array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    190 => 'Adana',
    58 => 'Ankara',
    199 => 'Antalya',
    205 => 'Aydın',
    226 => 'Kocaeli',
    228 => 'Mersin',
    233 => 'Nevşehir',
    236 => 'Sakarya',
    57 => 'İstanbul',
    56 => 'İzmir',
  ),
  57 => 
  array (
    420 => 'Anadolu Yakası',
    419 => 'Avrupa Yakası',
  ),
  419 => 
  array (
    158 => 'Avcılar',
    86 => 'Bahçelievler',
    160 => 'Bakırköy',
    87 => 'Bayrampaşa',
    161 => 'Başakşehir',
    162 => 'Beylikdüzü',
    163 => 'Beyoğlu',
    89 => 'Beşiktaş',
    164 => 'Büyükçekmece',
    503 => 'Esenyurt',
    95 => 'Eyüp',
    167 => 'Fatih',
    501 => 'Gaziosmanpaşa',
    96 => 'Güngören',
    422 => 'Kağıthane',
    176 => 'Küçükçekmece',
    103 => 'Sarıyer',
    542 => 'Silivri',
    508 => 'Sultangazi',
    189 => 'Zeytinburnu',
    105 => 'Şişli',
  ),
  420 => 
  array (
    172 => 'Adalar',
    85 => 'Ataşehir',
    90 => 'Beykoz',
    421 => 'Kadıköy',
    98 => 'Kartal',
    100 => 'Maltepe',
    102 => 'Pendik',
    536 => 'Tuzla',
    77 => 'Çekmeköy',
    187 => 'Ümraniye',
    107 => 'Üsküdar',
    104 => 'Şile',
  ),
  56 => 
  array (
    123 => 'Alsancak',
    215 => 'Balçova',
    124 => 'Bayraklı',
    125 => 'Bornova',
    216 => 'Buca',
    617 => 'Dikili',
    217 => 'Foça',
    218 => 'Gaziemir',
    220 => 'Güzelbahçe',
    507 => 'Karabağlar',
    128 => 'Karşıyaka',
    535 => 'Kemalpaşa',
    130 => 'Konak',
    222 => 'Menemen',
    132 => 'Narlıdere',
    223 => 'Seferihisar',
    559 => 'Tire',
    489 => 'Torbalı',
    225 => 'Urla',
    126 => 'Çeşme',
    127 => 'Çiğli',
  ),
  58 => 
  array (
    263 => 'Akyurt',
    428 => 'Altındağ',
    483 => 'Dikmen',
    116 => 'Etimesgut',
    117 => 'Gölbaşı',
    735 => 'Kahramankazan',
    459 => 'Keçiören',
    119 => 'Mamak',
    462 => 'Polatlı',
    120 => 'Pursaklar',
    430 => 'Sincan',
    122 => 'Yenimahalle',
    114 => 'Çankaya',
    453 => 'Çubuk',
    619 => 'Ümitköy',
  ),
  89 => 
  array (
    84 => 'Levent',
  ),
  117 => 
  array (
    520 => 'Kızılcaşar',
    195 => 'İncek',
  ),
  226 => 
  array (
    227 => 'Başiskele',
    625 => 'Gebze',
    667 => 'Kartepe',
  ),
  215 => 
  array (
    387 => 'İnciraltı',
  ),
  103 => 
  array (
    607 => 'Kilyos',
    178 => 'Maslak',
    106 => 'Tarabya',
  ),
  122 => 
  array (
    113 => 'Batıkent',
    198 => 'Ostim',
  ),
  216 => 
  array (
    129 => 'Kaynaklar',
  ),
  205 => 
  array (
    207 => 'Efeler',
    658 => 'Kuşadası',
    208 => 'Merkez',
  ),
  114 => 
  array (
    537 => 'Gaziosmanpaşa',
    118 => 'Kavaklıdere',
    197 => 'Söğütözü',
    115 => 'Çayyolu',
    623 => 'Çukurambar',
  ),
  100 => 
  array (
    177 => 'Küçükyalı',
    173 => 'İdealtepe',
  ),
  160 => 
  array (
    169 => 'Florya',
  ),
  163 => 
  array (
    524 => 'Karaköy',
  ),
  218 => 
  array (
    517 => 'Sarnıç',
  ),
  190 => 
  array (
    192 => 'Adnan Menderes',
    193 => 'Pozantı',
  ),
  96 => 
  array (
    602 => 'Merter',
  ),
  199 => 
  array (
    202 => 'Kaleiçi',
  ),
  228 => 
  array (
    230 => 'Merkez',
  ),
  126 => 
  array (
    544 => 'Dalyan',
  ),
  233 => 
  array (
    235 => 'Ürgüp',
  ),
  116 => 
  array (
    530 => 'Eryaman',
  ),
  236 => 
  array (
    237 => 'Sapanca',
  ),
  95 => 
  array (
    175 => 'Kemerburgaz',
  ),
  421 => 
  array (
    168 => 'Fenerbahçe',
  ),
  107 => 
  array (
    526 => 'Çamlıca',
  ),
  90 => 
  array (
    174 => 'Kavacık',
  ),
)
```

An example: Array[0] includes index key 57: which is İstanbul. In the array index key 57 contains İstanbul's sub categories, index of 420 "Avrupa Yakası" is sub category of istanbul and it has child categories listed in array.
I need to build a tree from Array[0] like this

```
İstanbul
 Avrupa Yakası
  Bahçelievler
 Anadolu Yakası
  Kadıköy
    Fenerbahçe
İzmir
 Alsancak
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

What about separating the parent from the sub-categories and looping through it to lookup the parent index, something like;

```
function tree($array){
  //Hold the parents in one array to us as a lookup
  $parents = $array[0];

  //Copy the array and remove the [0] parent element to allow simple
  //looping through the sub-category elements
  unset($array[0]);

  //Define the output array
  $output = [];
  $lookup = [];

 //Loop through the parents to find their sub cats
 //Append any sub-cat children as sub-elements of the subcat

 foreach($parents as $index => $category){
   $output[$category] = array_fill_keys(array_values($array[$index]), null);
   $lookup[$category] = $array[$index];
   foreach($lookup[$category] as $catindex => $subcat){
     if(isset($array[$catindex])){
       $output[$category][$subcat] = array_fill_keys(array_values($array[$catindex]), null);
     };
   };
 };

  return $output;
}
```

Working example at [Teh Playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/RsNvjf66531LdDw8) gives the following output;

```
Array
(
[Adana] => Array
    (
        [Adnan Menderes] => 
        [Pozantı] => 
    )

[Ankara] => Array
    (
        [Akyurt] => 
        [Altındağ] => 
        [Dikmen] => 
        [Etimesgut] => Array
            (
                [Eryaman] => 
            )

        [Gölbaşı] => Array
            (
                [Kızılcaşar] => 
                [İncek] => 
            )

        [Kahramankazan] => 
        [Keçiören] => 
        [Mamak] => 
        [Polatlı] => 
        [Pursaklar] => 
        [Sincan] => 
        [Yenimahalle] => Array
            (
                [Batıkent] => 
                [Ostim] => 
            )

        [Çankaya] => Array
            (
                [Gaziosmanpaşa] => 
                [Kavaklıdere] => 
                [Söğütözü] => 
                [Çayyolu] => 
                [Çukurambar] => 
            )

        [Çubuk] => 
        [Ümitköy] => 
    )

[Antalya] => Array
    (
        [Kaleiçi] => 
    )

[Aydın] => Array
    (
        [Efeler] => 
        [Kuşadası] => 
        [Merkez] => 
    )

[Kocaeli] => Array
    (
        [Başiskele] => 
        [Gebze] => 
        [Kartepe] => 
    )

[Mersin] => Array
    (
        [Merkez] => 
    )

[Nevşehir] => Array
    (
        [Ürgüp] => 
    )

[Sakarya] => Array
    (
        [Sapanca] => 
    )

[İstanbul] => Array
    (
        [Anadolu Yakası] => Array
            (
                [Adalar] => 
                [Ataşehir] => 
                [Beykoz] => 
                [Kadıköy] => 
                [Kartal] => 
                [Maltepe] => 
                [Pendik] => 
                [Tuzla] => 
                [Çekmeköy] => 
                [Ümraniye] => 
                [Üsküdar] => 
                [Şile] => 
            )

        [Avrupa Yakası] => Array
            (
                [Avcılar] => 
                [Bahçelievler] => 
                [Bakırköy] => 
                [Bayrampaşa] => 
                [Başakşehir] => 
                [Beylikdüzü] => 
                [Beyoğlu] => 
                [Beşiktaş] => 
                [Büyükçekmece] => 
                [Esenyurt] => 
                [Eyüp] => 
                [Fatih] => 
                [Gaziosmanpaşa] => 
                [Güngören] => 
                [Kağıthane] => 
                [Küçükçekmece] => 
                [Sarıyer] => 
                [Silivri] => 
                [Sultangazi] => 
                [Zeytinburnu] => 
                [Şişli] => 
            )

    )

[İzmir] => Array
    (
        [Alsancak] => 
        [Balçova] => Array
            (
                [İnciraltı] => 
            )

        [Bayraklı] => 
        [Bornova] => 
        [Buca] => Array
            (
                [Kaynaklar] => 
            )

        [Dikili] => 
        [Foça] => 
        [Gaziemir] => Array
            (
                [Sarnıç] => 
            )

        [Güzelbahçe] => 
        [Karabağlar] => 
        [Karşıyaka] => 
        [Kemalpaşa] => 
        [Konak] => 
        [Menemen] => 
        [Narlıdere] => 
        [Seferihisar] => 
        [Tire] => 
        [Torbalı] => 
        [Urla] => 
        [Çeşme] => Array
            (
                [Dalyan] => 
            )

        [Çiğli] => 
    )
```

It's not *ideal* that each lowest level child element is empty, but it was the only way to output the values in the tree formation without inferring numerical indexes, and also simplified the code for handling the variable depth per top level parent element.